# Bandwidth monitoring on Windows desktop with world map

Tags: windows-10, bandwidth

have used Little Snitch on OSX and found its network monitor to be really useful

[image: Little Snitch Network Monitor]

does anyone know of a program on Windows that can show, on a world map, which countries my computer is connecting to ? GlassWire comes close but does not display a map of traffic.